# how to add modify headers to the fifrefox profile and run the test in the iphone user agent using selenium webdriver

Tags: webdriver

how to add modify headers to the fifrefox profile and run the test in  the user agent Value: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11. for that i have used the below code fp is the firefox

```
profile object fp.setEnableNativeEvents(true);                  
File file = new File("C:\\FirefoxProfile\\modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi");
//File file = new File("C:\\AddOn");
fp.addExtension(file);
fp.setPreference("extensions.modify_headers.currentVersion", "0.7.1.1-fx");
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", true);
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 2);
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.action1", "Modify");
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "User-Agent");
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11");
fp.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", true);
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's much simpler way of modifying user agent than using an add-on. All you need to do is assign a new value to Firefox `general.useragent.override` setting.

```java
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "My new shiny user agent");     
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

driver.get("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/");
```

Comment: is this the way i have to give fp.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");

Comment: and what should i give exactly in driver.get("http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/"); , we should give the base  url of our applicatioj here right

Comment: Yes, what you've written in your first comment is correct. As for `driver.get(...)` I just wrote it so you can instantly verify that changing user agent worked. You don't give base url there, you should pass a url of the website you want to test.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really keen to work with the Modify header :

1. Make sure Modify-header is included in your project, and it is accessible

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File modifyHeaders = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi");

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
try {
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false);
    profile.addExtension(modifyHeaders);
    profile.setPreference("extensions.modify_headers.currentVersion", "0.7.1.1-fx");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "User-Agent");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7D11");
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", true);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.active", true);
    profile.setPreference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", true);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capabilities.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

    driver.get("https://google.com.au");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// .... the rest}
```